# Give an example of set $A$ such that for $B = \{ 1, 3, 4, 8\}$ and $A - (B - A)=\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11\}$

Tags: elementary-set-theory

This question has been driving me insane for the past 3 hours.

Give an example of set $A$ such that for $B=\{1,3,4,8\}$ and $A - (B - A)= \{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11\}$

I understand that the subtraction of a set is every element in the first set that is not included in the second set or shared with the second set. However I just cannot find an answer to this question no matter what I try.

Comment: Welcome to MathSE! You are more likely to get a good answer to your question if you follow a few guidelines in your question.  In particular, make your question clear. Is that supposed to be "$A - (B - A) =\{ 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 9, 10, 11\}$"? You seem to have left out an equals sign (or something similar).

Comment: yes sorry, the question should read...
A−(B−A) = {1,2,3,4,5,6,9,10,11}

Comment: **HINT:** $B-A$ will leave you with a set that cannot contain any elements that are in $A$ - lets call this $C$. Therefore $A-C$ is saying substract from $A$ the elements of $C$ - but $C$ does not share any elements with $A$. Therefore...

Comment: does this mean A must include all the elements of the final set?

Comment: Yes - in fact $A$ **is** the final set :)

Answer (score 3):

**HINT:** Look at the definition of $B-A$. Remember that $X-Y=X-(Y\cap X)$. Now conclude that $A-(B-A)$ can be greatly simplified.

Comment: but i don't understand how A - (B - A) can be simplified sorry, i am fairly new to sets!!

Comment: @TomPhill If $x \in A-(B-A)$, then that means that $x \in A$, and at the same time $x \notin B-A$. But since $x$ is an element of $A$, it is automatically not an element of $B-A$, so the second condition is redundant. Therefore any element in $A-(B-A)$ is an element of $A$, and vice versa.

Comment: @Tom: $A-(B-A)=A-((B-A)\cap A)$. What is the intersection of $A$ and $B-A$? Can you proceed now?

Comment: Yes thank you guys for your help, this is so much clearer now!!

Answer (score 1):

Whatever the sets $A$ and $B$, the set $D:=B\setminus A$ contains only objects that are extraneous to $A$. Therefore, subtracting $D$ from $A$ does nothing to $A$.

Comment: Thank you guys.Very informative answer.In maths,its always better to know how you get to the answer than getting the answer itself